# Any reason to not use Proptypes in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I see lot of articles stating that Proptypes in React components are useful for validation. But are there any use cases, where we should not use Proptypes? Or should we always use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropTypes are suggested by React developers and mentioned in the official documentation page as well. I don't think there is any case where we shouldn't use PropTypes as it improves the code quality.

Though if you are using TypeScript in React, then prop-types doesn't make any sense to be used.

Comment: this is not true anymore.